# How to use NSPredicate to find a title in CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

if I want to find the word "color" in the string "red is a color in my crayonbox", how to I structure it?

Thank you,

Comment: could you explain? I am searching a core data base

Comment: How would I implement that below? ||NSPredicate *predicate2=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY name MATCHES[cd] %@",string];//CONTAINS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *stringToSearchFor = @"whatever you want";

[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] %@", stringToSearchFor];
```

To search for red OR ferrari...

```
NSPredicate *redPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] 'red'"];

NSPredicate *ferraiPred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[cd] 'ferrari'"];

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubPredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:redPred, ferrariPred, nil]];
```

Comment: what if my search string is "the color red" and I want to pull up a result named "red" (so there are excess words in my search string)

Comment: thank you, however I tried searching (query string)"red cars drive fast" looking for the result "red ferrari" and it didn't find the results

Comment: Yes, that's because "red cars drive fast" doesn't contain "red ferrari".

Comment: do I have to split the string into words and add to an array?

Comment: No, you need to ask the correct question in the first place. If you want to search for multiple contains then you need to use AND and OR as necessary. You can find more info about this here... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html